# Police Data API

Tags: android, json, api

I am a little bit stuck when trying to get data from the PoliceData Api.

Here's my code:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Latest_crimes extends AppCompatActivity {

    String Crimes_Url;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_latest_crimes);


        Crimes_Url = "https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat=52.629729&lng=-1.131592&date=2017-01";
        new Latest_crimes.AsyncHttpTask().execute(Crimes_Url);
    }



    String streamToString(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferesReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        String data;
        String result = "";
        while ((data = bufferesReader.readLine()) != null) {
            result += data;
        }
        if (null != stream) {
            stream.close();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void parseResult(String result) {
        JSONObject response = null;
        try {
            response = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray crimes = response.optJSONArray("category");

            for (int i = 0; i < crimes.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject crime = crimes.optJSONObject(i);
                String category = crimes.getJSONObject(0).getString("category");
                Log.i("Title", category);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                String response = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                parseResult(response);
                return result;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

When it's running I got this error:

> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException and data are not shown in the
>   right format.

I am new to JSON and Android studio and basically, I don't know what have I done wrong.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

LE:

> 11-21 19:09:24.997 8236-8257/com.example.cosmin.crimeratev001
>   W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value
>   [{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"52.632469","street":{"id":883334,"name":"On
>   or near Pocklingtons Walk"}
>
> 11-21 19:09:24.997
>   8236-8257/com.example.cosmin.crimeratev001 W/System.err:     at
>   org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
>
> 11-21 19:09:24.997
>   8236-8257/com.example.cosmin.crimeratev001 W/System.err:     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:160)
>
> 11-21 19:09:24.997
>   8236-8257/com.example.cosmin.crimeratev001 W/System.err:     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:173)
>
> 11-21 19:09:24.997
>   8236-8257/com.example.cosmin.crimeratev001 W/System.err:     at com.example.cosmin.crimeratev001.Latest_crimes.parseResult(Latest_crimes.java:49)
>
> 11-21 19:09:24.997 8236-8257/com.example.cosmin.crimeratev001
>   W/System.err: at com.example.cosmin.crimeratev001.Latest_crimes.access$000(Latest_crimes.java:18)
>
> 11-21 19:09:24.997 8236-8257/com.example.cosmin.crimeratev001
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.cosmin.crimeratev001.Latest_crimes$AsyncHttpTask.doInBackground(Latest_crimes.java:75)
>
> 11-21 19:09:24.997 8236-8257/com.example.cosmin.crimeratev001
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.cosmin.crimeratev001.Latest_crimes$AsyncHttpTask.doInBackground(Latest_crimes.java:64)
>
> 11-21 19:09:24.997 8236-8257/com.example.cosmin.crimeratev001
>   W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
>
> 11-21 19:09:24.997 8236-8257/com.example.cosmin.crimeratev001
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>
> 11-21 19:09:24.997 8236-8257/com.example.cosmin.crimeratev001 W/System.err: 
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
>
> 11-21 19:09:24.997 8236-8257/com.example.cosmin.crimeratev001 W/System.err: 
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>
> 11-21 19:09:24.997 8236-8257/com.example.cosmin.crimeratev001
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>
> 11-21 19:09:24.998 8236-8257/com.example.cosmin.crimeratev001
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Comment: You should be using a library like Retrofit(https://github.com/square/retrofit) for networking. I hate that the official docs still recommend using `AsyncTasks`  and `HttpUrlConnection` for networling

Comment: You need to show the full stacktrace or log output.